# if exists statement between a case when condition sql

Tags: sql, case

In the middle of my stored procedure, I have the following snippet of code:

```
case
  when l.codeleasestatuscode = '5' and priorleaseid is null 
  and l.leaid in(select col1 from Waitlisthousehold)
then '2'
else l.codeleasestatuscode
end
```

however, the final condition, wherein i have to select from the table Waitlisthousehold, has an issue. Not all databases has that table. so I want that last condition to be included when the table exists. But i'm getting errors when i try to do this:

```
case
when l.codeleasestatuscode = '5' and priorleaseid is null
IF EXISTS(select * from information_schema.tables where table_name='WaitlistHousehold')
  begin
    and l.leaid in(select col1 from Waitlisthousehold)
  end
then '2'
else l.codeleasestatuscode
end
```

So how do i do it correctly?

This snippet is inside a from statement(from table1 a join table2 b on a.id=b.id and case when..)

Comment: Guessing at SQL Server? If so, there's no way to do this without using dynamic SQL - each query is fixed in terms of the tables that it accesses.

Answer (score 3):

you can have another case when clause inside your one to check if the table exist or not

```
CASE
WHEN l.codeleasestatuscode = '5' and priorleaseid is null
    CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='WaitlistHousehold')
        THEN
            CASE WHEN l.leaid in(select col1 from Waitlisthousehold) THEN '2' 
            ELSE l.codeleasestatuscode END
        ELSE '2' END          
    THEN '2'END
ELSE l.codeleasestatuscode
END
```

Comment: Thanks for EXISTS in CASE expression, but this snippet will return an error incorrect syntax

Comment: haha.. I wrote CASE WHERE instead of CASE WHEN, check the answer now

Comment: Like  Damien_The_Unbeliever said, this won't work in SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

you can't add an if inside the select statement like that. you could do this:

```
IF EXISTS(select * from information_schema.tables where table_name='WaitlistHousehold')
  BEGIN
  SELECT whatever,
  case
  when l.codeleasestatuscode = '5' and priorleaseid is null
    and l.leaid in(select col1 from Waitlisthousehold)
  then '2'
  else l.codeleasestatuscode
  end AS whatever1
  FROM wherever
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
  SELECT whatever,
  case
  when l.codeleasestatuscode = '5' and priorleaseid is null
  then '2'
  else l.codeleasestatuscode
  end AS whatever1
  FROM wherever
  END
```

Comment: If it's SQL Server (as seems likely given the OP's previous questions) this won't work, because it will attempt to compile the entire batch, and the absence of the table will prevent that compilation from succeeding.