# using EXISTS to check duplicated usernames

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I've been checking the best way to check for duplicated usernames And i saw people saying EXISTS is better for performance, Is this formula is good? Or is there any better ones? And what is the difference between, `IF EXISTS` and `SELECT EXISTS` and `WHEN EXISTS`? And is it possible to merge email inside the code and to check both email and username at the same time? Or is it better to separate both quires?

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username)");
    $stmt->execute([':username' => $username]);
    if ($stmt->fetchColumn() > 0) {
        echo "Username is already taken.";
    }
```

Comment: what is your rdbms? If your query works, I cant think anything better. And yes you can check for both email and user at the same time, just add `OR` condition.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza but can i specify which one of them is false and `echo`? Or that why separating them is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return bit if true then 1 else False 0

```
    SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username
    )
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
    END AS result
```

Comment: Can you be more explanatory? Like why is this better than the other one.

Comment: if your result needs true or false as output you can use above query which doesn't  affect the performance.It is use  check  the existence of a record also having subquery joining multiple tables to check the record existence in multiple tables

Comment: So there is no difference between my code and yours except defining if it is true or false?

Comment: Not is single case if there are some more cases then my query would work in that condition. Just the case you get the flag or user defined values which they can customize accordingly

Comment: I would like if you add an another example of using two or three queries using your code, For the answer to be perfect, But i was wondering, How does 1 AS BIT is called using php? Is it like `$bit = BIT`?

Comment: You can have a look at this [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074287/if-exists-statement-between-a-case-when-condition-sql ]

Answer (score 0):

You can set username or email as unique key. Then use try .. catch

```
try {
  // do your insert query. If it fails to insert, it will throw error message
  // Also need to turn on error exception mode for PDO attribute
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

You can use SQL:

- SQL COUNT

  $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(username) AS total FROM users WHERE   username = :username');

  // Or $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(username) AS total FROM users where username = :username AND email = :email');

  $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
  $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
  $stmt->execute();
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  if ($row->total > 0) {
     echo 'Username/Email already taken.';
  }

  [1]: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php

Comment: That how was my code looking before searching about EXISTS, people says that EXISTS is faster than COUNT in many ways because it stops directly when finds ONE row with the value.

Comment: :) then you might need to dump speed between both queries